# Docker Swarm Replications on Manager and worker Noeds

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to spin up my application which uses MySQL and PHP on Docker Swarm. I do have one Manager and two worker nodes and I need to replicate the MySQL and PHP containers on each nodes. If I use the option mode: global then it will create one container of each MySQL and PHP on Manager and Worker nodes but in this scenario replication won't work.

If I use the mode as replicated and placement constraints `node.role == manager` or `node.role == worker` then the containers will create on that  particular constraints only. My Question is If I use `replicas=3` for MySQL or PHP, how can I get at least one MySQL and PHP containers on each Manager and Worker nodes?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 3 managers and 3 workers.

Keep the placement constraints and deploy in `mode: global`, as it will instantiate in every node that obeys to that constraint. [View Official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#set-service-mode---mode).